# How to overriding style for multilingual with RTL in magento2.1?

Tags: magento2, theme

I have multilingual site in magento 2 and extended blank theme , i want to know where can i overwrite style for RTL(Arabic language) `direction: rtl` and other common and module wise style as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new theme for `RTL` (assign parent your default theme) at below path given below:

```
app\design\frontend\vendor\
```

create `Store View` in admin and apply created theme for that `Store View` given path below

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

edit your created `store view` and apply theme which you created for `RTL`.

```
 - php bin/magento cache:clean
 - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now you can overwrite your default style for `RTL`

Comment: I have only english store view, can we override it to RTL ?

Comment: Yes you can override with, `<html lang="ar-SA">` tag with this style
`html[lang='ar-SA'] body {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: embed;
}`